# Allow Regular Users to Own/Manage Groups in Google Apps Mail

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, google-groups

We have numerous groups in our Google Apps domain - most of them are administered by the SysAdmin (who has full privileges) but we want some of them to be administered by other users (who only have standard privileges).

I've found how to set those users as the owner of the groups, but can't seem to find where those users can actually administer the groups once they've been set as the owner.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find where in the free version of Google Apps changing from Member to Owner has any effect. However, you can assign the person a new role (beyond user) in the control panel which includes managing Groups for your domain:

https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2405986

If you are in Google Apps for Business and have enabled Google Groups for Business, then they will be able to administer the group from Groups as an owner.

https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166147

Answer (score 1):

Alex, it looks like your question is "how can the users manager the group after they have been granted the **owner** or **manager** permission?"

The page you need can be reached by modifying the following URL, where `<yourgroupname>@<yourdomain> == yourgroup@example.com`:

```
https://groups.google.com/a/<yourdomain>/forum/#!managemembers/<yourgroupname>/members/active
```